# How to manage sys.path in pytest that's running systems configuration acceptance tests

Tags: python, ansible, pytest

We have a test framework that extends pytest slightly, and wraps it in a lot of Ansible in order to run systems configuration acceptance tests to verify that our infrastructure has been installed and configured correctly, and seems to be running sanely. It does this by using Ansible to package up the tests, send them to a remote host, then unpack them into a virtualenv to run the tests in. Most people's tests so far involve running commands on the remote host to verify they work.

Part of what I'm trying to test is whether or not some Python modules are installed and working, and if they are, use them in further tests. But I'm somewhat stymied in this in that the virtualenv (quite rightly) hides all the system installed Python modules.

So far, my strategy is to run a `subprocess` shell command/small script that unsets all the virtualenv related environment variables and then runs a short Python script using the system python that pickles its `sys.path` and dumps it to stdout.

But then I'm not sure about the next step. What is the right way to mess with `sys.path` inside of a test or a fixture?  Will pytest restore it once the fixture is no longer needed?  What does pytest do with modules that a test imports?  Does it remove them from sys.modules after the test is done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I didn't get an answer, so I came up with this fixture to put in `conftest.py`:

```
@pytest.fixture(scope="module")
def need_system_libraries():
    pycmd = 'unset VIRTUAL_ENV PYTHONPATH; exec {pyexec} -c '\
            '"import sys, pickle; sys.stdout.write(pickle.dumps(sys.path, 0))"'

    pycmd = pycmd.format(pyexec='/usr/bin/python3.7')
    _, stdout, _ = testlib.execute(pycmd)
    system_path = pickle.loads(stdout)
    # Prune any paths from the system_path that already exist in sys.path or     
    # are relative (not absolute) paths.                                         
    newsyspaths = frozenset(system_path) - frozenset(sys.path)
    newsyspaths = frozenset(path for path in newsyspaths
                            if os.path.isabs(path))
    # A set isn't ordered. Put difference back in the same order as the          
    # elements appeared in system_path. (Not needed in Python >= 3.6).           
    newsyspaths = [path for path in system_path if x in newsyspaths]
    # Save a copy of the path so we can restore it.                              
    saved_syspath = sys.path.copy()
    sys.path.extend(newsyspaths)
    # This fixture modifies the environment itself, and so doesn't need to       
    # return a value.                                                            
    yield None
    # The yield will come back when this fixture is no longer needed, so         
    # restore sys.path back to its original value. Do this by copying elements   
    # back into original sys.path in case the identity of sys.path is important  
    # somewhere deep in the bowels of Python.                                    
    sys.path[:] = saved_syspath
```